# Using node and express, how do I create user friendly URLs?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I just completed Colt Steele's Web Developer bootcamp and starting to create my own application.

My question is using MongoDB, Express and Node, I see that the URLS that are created are like http://localhost/category/122398753984 where the number is the MongoDB _id number.

Is it possible to code in such a way to use the category name? For example http://localhost/category/finance where it shows the category name instead of an id value.  If it is possible, how do I also deal with conflicting names, for example someone also enters in finance as a category name.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course you can just add a new field to your category model.

```
category: {
 _id: ObjectId,
 name: "Finance",
 slug: "finance"
}
```

Now when you create a route:

```
router.get('/category/:slug', function(req, res) {
   const slug = req.params.slug;
   const category = // query database using slug value.
   return res.json(category);
})
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to prevent from having duplicate slugs?

Comment: Yes you can add unique index on slug field in mongoose schema. also before inserting new category search for existing category with newly inserted slug , if there is a category with the same then return the error message to user.